# When one of the p tag is not empty, hide other p tag

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml, paragraph

I am having the structure like this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fy0kpc0/).

What I want to do is that: When the class ("discount") is not empty, the other 3 p tags will be hidden. When the class ("discount") is empty, the other 3 p tags will be shown.

I have been trying

```
if($('.discount).is(':not("empty)'))
```

or

```
.discount.innerHTML.length != 0
```

But all are not working. Can anyone give me some solution of it?

Comment: Your logic is not totally clear.  So - if _any one_ of the `p` tags has contents, you want the _other_ `p` tags to be hidden? (Out of curiosity, why? An empty `p` tag can be styled with CSS to be hidden...) - what if more than one `p` tag has content? Should all `p` tags with content be visible, but others without content hidden?

Comment: Further to the previous comment, please post the "*[mcve]*" code *here* in the question; live code in an external site is a bonus, but the relevant code must be included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do this as follows:

```js
$('.discount').not(':empty').parent().siblings().hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Info 1</h4>
<div class="information">
  <p class="s">
    <em class="discount">DISCOUNT PROMOTION</em>
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Title
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Name
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Detail
  </p>
  
</div>

<h4>Info 2</h4>
<div class="information">
  <p class="s">
    <em class="discount"></em>
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Title
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Name
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Detail
  </p>
  
</div>

<h4>Info 3</h4>
<div class="information">
  <p class="s">
    <em class="discount">DISCOUNT PROMOTION</em>
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Title
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Name
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Detail
  </p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Note this is instance specific because internally jQuery will go through each `.discount` whereas the other approaches only return value of the first one found

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/0fy0kpc0/1/

```js
$(function(){
  if($('.discount').html().length){
   console.log("yeah!")
   $('.information p:nth-child(2)').hide();
   $('.information p:nth-child(3)').hide();
   $('.information p:nth-child(4)').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="information">
  <p class="s">
    <em class="discount">DISCOUNT PROMOTION</em>
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Title
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Name
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Detail
  </p>
  
</div>
```

Mistake was in `.discount.innerHTML.length != 0` line in jsfiddle

Here you go with one more solution https://jsfiddle.net/0fy0kpc0/2/

```js
$(function(){
  if (!$('.discount').is(':empty')){
    console.log("yeah!")
    $('.information p:nth-child(2)').hide();
    $('.information p:nth-child(3)').hide();
    $('.information p:nth-child(4)').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="information">
  <p class="s">
    <em class="discount">DISCOUNT PROMOTION</em>
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Title
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Name
  </p>
  <p class="s">
    Detail
  </p>
  
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I can understand your answer, but for the first solution, I have got from console the length is 0, but still the other p tags are not hidden... and the second solutions also didn't work for me

Comment: @Sammi Are you looking for, if `.discount` length is 0 then p tags will be hidden?

Comment: Will fail if you add another `information` block. Code is not instance specific

Answer (score 0):

Try with `:not()` and `:has()` selector:

```
$(function(){

 if($('.discount').text().length != 0)
 {

   $("p:not(:has(>em))").hide();
    }
});
```